# Connected grey lines for comparison

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know how to fix an issue with the output below. The ggplot shows a gray line of all data plotted, but the gray lines do not appear the way I would like it. I would like the gray lines to be lines representing the outline of all of the black lines and then added across all facets, but the gray lines look like they are all points connected randomly (see regions in blue circles). How could I change the code to format the gray lines to my liking?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_line(data = transform(mpg, class = NULL), colour = "grey85") +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(vars(class))
```

[image]

Comment: If you put the `geom_line()` before `geom_line(data = transform(mpg, class = NULL), colour = "grey85")` is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the lines to be grouped according to `class` in every facet, but you also want to facet on class. One way to achieve this is to pass a data frame to the `geom_line` call that has a renamed `class` column:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_line(data = mpg %>% mutate(class2 = class) %>% select(-class),
            colour = "grey75", aes(group = class2)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(vars(class))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had tried something similar to your solution, but just didn't remove the faceting variable from the df.